# How to make a list of unique items from a column w/ repeats in PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, list, unique

Say I have a table that has a column which goes:

```
Column B
apple
apple
apple
orange
apple
orange
orange
grapes
grapes
mango
mango
orange
```

And I want to query it in such a way that I get a list like so:

apple
orange
grapes
mango

How do I do this in PHP SQL? Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is called 'Fruit' and this column is called 'B'. Here's how you would do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B FROM Fruit;
```

The 'DISTINCT' keyword will get you all unique results.
That's the SQL part. In PHP, you write the query like this:

```
// Perform Query
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT B FROM Fruit';
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Get result
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['B'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to do the actual filtering?  SQL or PHP?

For SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM table;
#or#
SELECT foo FROM table GROUP BY foo;
```

For PHP:

```
$foo = array('a','a','b','b','c');
$foo_filtered = array_unique($foo);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Moot. There's another thing I learned array. But say I don't even know what the array is gonna be — just values from a table that keeps adding to itself. So what do I do? Much thanks.