# Print same values once in a while loop

Tags: php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname");
while($fetch =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$name = $fetch['name'];

echo "$name";

}
```

In my example, after echoing out $name in a while, the values are:

```
Carrots
Lemon
Carrots
Lemon
```

Is there a way to not repeat printing the same value that will look like this:

```
Carrots
Lemon
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a list of unique items from a column w/ repeats in PHP SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771777/how-to-make-a-list-of-unique-items-from-a-column-w-repeats-in-php-sql)

Answer (score 7):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tblname");
while($fetch =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $fetch['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name` FROM tblname;
```

or

```
SELECT `name` FROM tblname GROUP BY `name`;
```

PHP Solution:

```
$my_array = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname");

while($fetch =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $my_array[] = $fetch['name'];
}

$my_array = array_unique($my_array);

echo implode('<br />', $my_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname");
while($fetch =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $name = $fetch['name'];

  if (!in_array($name,$names)){
    echo "$name"; 
    $names[] = $name;
  }
}
```

Will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT  table1.id, table2.id, table2.name 
FROM table1, table2 WHERE id=id GROUP BY name");
```

This Will Work 100% sure. 
SET `GROUP BY name` and `DISTINCT`. If not it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append them into an array like:

```
$items[] = $item;
```

After that do:

```
$items = array_unique($items);
```

After that, simply print the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch them all into an array and then run `array_unique()`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname");
$arr = array();
while($fetch =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $arr[] = $fetch;
}

$output = array_unique($arr);
foreach ($output as $uniqe_val) {
   echo $unique_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the question ambiguous.  I *think* you're asking for what appears in [How to make a list of unique items from a column w/ repeats in PHP SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771777/how-to-make-a-list-of-unique-items-from-a-column-w-repeats-in-php-sql)